# setOnItemSelectedListener is not working when dynamically filling items in spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

What I am are trying to do is:-
To show states in spinner load it from database and fill the spinner. on selection state, depending on state, the city must be filled in another spinner.

What I achieved is:
Spinner get filled with the values from database, but the `setOnItemSelectedListener` is not working.

`setOnItemSelectedListener` method works when I put data statically in the spinner.

My Source:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Spinner sp_state,sp_city,sp_area;
    Button ok;
    int state_position;
    String s_data,c_data,a_data,selected_state;
    ArrayList<Satae_Pojo> new_data;
    Network_Class net=new Network_Class();
    ArrayList<Satae_Pojo> state=new ArrayList<Satae_Pojo>();
    ArrayList<Integer> state_id=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> state_name=new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_for_area);
        sp_state=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_state);
        sp_city=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_city);
        sp_area=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_area);
        ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);

        List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Please Select Area");
        list.add("Phulewadi");
        list.add("Vikramnagar");
        list.add("Kadamwadi");
        list.add("Rajarampuri");

        getStates();

        sp_state.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) 
            {
                System.out.println("This is spinner");

                //String id=parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                //System.out.println("This is selected id  "+id);

            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
        });

        ArrayAdapter<String> state_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, state_name);
        state_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp_state.setAdapter(state_adapter);

    }

    public void getStates()
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                s_data=net.getState();
                ArrayList<Satae_Pojo> statedata = statepojo(s_data);
                Iterator<Satae_Pojo> itr = statedata.iterator();
                while(itr.hasNext())
                {

                    Satae_Pojo s_pojo=(Satae_Pojo)itr.next();
                    int id=(Integer)s_pojo.getId();
                    String name=(String)s_pojo.getState();

                    state_id.add(id);
                    state_name.add(name);
                }       
            }
        }).start(); 
    }

    public ArrayList<Satae_Pojo> statepojo(String result)
    {
        ArrayList<Satae_Pojo> states=new ArrayList<Satae_Pojo>();
        try
        {

            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0; i<jsonarray.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonobject=jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                Satae_Pojo statepojo=new Satae_Pojo();

                statepojo.setId(jsonobject.getInt("id"));
                statepojo.setState(jsonobject.getString("s_name"));

                states.add(statepojo);

            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e("Log_tag", "Error Parsing in State....."+e.toString());
            Log.e("Log_Answers","Second Error Parsing in State....."+result);
        }
        return states;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

In above source when I pass "list" as argument to adapter it works fine.
but when dynamically filled state_name is passed setOnItemSelectedListener do not work.. what I am doing wrong..?

Comment: Try String id=parent.getAdapter().getItem(pos).toString()

Comment: I have tried that... this do not  works. see in the comments just bellow System.out.println("This is spinner"); even this System.out.println("This is spinner"); do not print the value in it.

Comment: what u have tried is parent.getItemAtPosition(pos) what i wrote is parent.getAdapter().getItem(pos)

Comment: Sorry I tried but it do not work. just focus even the first System.out.println("This is spinner"); is not printing. how it will go to next line of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are adding data (dynamically) to adapter you need to call `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` so that the view will refresh it self.

add this code after while loop of `getStates()` method

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            state_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Bdy, but can you explain me why is it so..? why Listener was not printing message.

Comment: because you didnt have the data for the listener. Its not about listener its about your data set attached to your view(spinner) and adapter. After setAdapter if you made changes in your dataset you have to call notifyDatesetChanged to refresh views with new data available.

Comment: Man you saved my life, totally working after adding adapter.notifydatasetchanged